# I can not figure out why my for loop is not being taken in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, polynomials

In MATLAB, I am trying to write a program that will take 3 coordinates on a graph, (x,y), use those values to solve a system of equations that will find the coefficients of a polynomial equation, y = ax^2 + bx + c, which I can then use to plot a parabola.

To test my code, I figured I could start with a polynomial, graph it, find the minimum location of the parabola, use its immediate neighbors for my other 2 locations, then run those 3 locations through my code which should spit out the coefficients of my original polynomial. But for some reason, my resulting parabola is right shifted and my values for b and c are incorrect.

Does anyone see where my issue is? I am out of ideas

```
clear all; close all;

x = -10:10;

%Original Polynomial
y = 6.*x.^2 + 11.*x -35;

% Find 3 Locations
[max_n, max_i] = min(y)
max_il = max_i - 1                 % left neighbor of max_ni
max_nl = y(max_il)                 % value at max_il
max_ir = max_i + 1                 % left neighbor of max_ni
max_nr = y(max_ir)                 % value at max_ir

% Solve for coefficients
syms a b c
equ = (a)*(max_i)^2 + (b)*(max_i) + (c) == (max_n);
equ_l = (a)*(max_il)^2 + (b)*(max_il) + (c) == (max_nl);
equ_r = (a)*(max_ir)^2 + (b)*(max_ir) + (c) == (max_nr);

sol = solve([equ, equ_l, equ_r],[a, b, c]);

Sola = sol.a
Solb = sol.b
Solc = sol.c

% New Polynomial
p = (sol.a).*(x).^2 + (sol.b).*(x) +(sol.c);


%Plot
plot(x,y); grid on; hold on;
plot(x, p); 
axis([-10 10 -41 40])
[max_np, max_ip] = min(p)
legend('OG', 'New')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: How is the title related to the body of the post? What for loop are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the index into your array `y`, and the corresponding x coordinate.

```matlab
x = -10:10;
y = 6.*x.^2 + 11.*x -35;

[max_n, max_i] = min(y)
```

Here. `max_i` is the index into the `y` array, the corresponding x coordinate would be `x(max_i)`.

I suggest you find three data points to fit your curve to as follows:

```matlab
[~, max_i] = min(y);
pts_x = x(max_i + (-1:1));
pts_y = y(max_i + (-1:1));
```

then use `pts_x(i)` and `pts_y(i)` as your x and y values:

```matlab
syms a b c
equ = a * pts_x.^2 + b * pts_x + c == pts_y;
sol = solve(equ, [a, b, c]);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your eyes on this. That is indeed my problem